# SQL Server generates System Argument Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem with a query in SQL Server in C#, this part of the queue prepares a query to print with Microsoft report. My problem is that when it is hit `(checkedListBoxCosaStampare.SelectedIndex == 1)` I get the error listed below.

I also have another problem, when checked 2 items from the *checklistbox* run only the second *if*. How can I fix it ?

Error:

[image]

C# code:

```
// Stampa completa con prezzo
if (comboBoxStampe.Text== "Stampa con Prezzo")
{              
    try
    {
        //contro i valori cekkati:
        int contacheck = 0;
        //Devo effettuare tutti i controlli

        //Il ricarico non funziona correttamente con il punto quindi controllo se è presente il punto se c'è lo 
        //sostituisco con la ,
        if (textBoxRicarico.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            textBoxRicarico.Text = textBoxRicarico.Text.Replace(".", ",");
        }

        float Ricarico = float.Parse(textBoxRicarico.Text);

        //Setto la parte iniziale della query
        String Query = "SET LANGUAGE 'Italian' select Tipo, Data, GG, CodArt as 'CodArt',Descrizione,Quantita as 'Quantita',Prezzo,Totale from (  ";

        //Prima parte della query

        //controllo se gli articoli sono selezionati
        if (checkedListBoxCosaStampare.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {                        
            Query = Query + "Select 'A' as Tipo, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ArticoloCantiere.DataInserimento, 105) as Data, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, ArticoloCantiere.DataInserimento) as GG, ArticoloCantiere.CodArt, ArticoloCantiere.Descrizione, ArticoloCantiere.Quantita, (ArticoloCantiere.Prezzo+((ArticoloCantiere.Prezzo/100)*'"+Ricarico+"')) as Prezzo, (ArticoloCantiere.Prezzo+((ArticoloCantiere.Prezzo/100)*'"+Ricarico+"'))*Quantita as Totale  from Cantiere  inner join ArticoloCantiere  on Cantiere.IdCantiere = ArticoloCantiere.IdCantiere  where ArticoloCantiere.IdCantiere = '"+IdCantiere+"'  ";
            contacheck++;
        }

        //controllo le spese sostenute
        if (checkedListBoxCosaStampare.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            //controllo se è stato precendentemente selezionato qualcosa
            if (contacheck >0)
            {
                Query = Query + " union ";
            }

            Query = Query + " Select 'S' as Tipo, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SpeseSostenute.Data, 105) as Data, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, SpeseSostenute.Data) as GG, '' as CodArt, 'Causale: ' + SpeseSostenute.Causale + ' --- Descrizione: ' + DescrizioneLibera as Descrizione, '' as Quantita, (SpeseSostenute.Costo+((SpeseSostenute.Costo/100)*'"+Ricarico+"')) as Prezzo, '' as Totale  from SpeseSostenute  where IdCantiere = '"+IdCantiere+"'  ";
        }

        //setto la parte finale della query
        Query = Query + "    )Q order by Data ";

        MessageBox.Show("Mostra Query "+Query);

        //eseguo la stampa
        StampaCompletaCantiereconPrezzo s = new StampaCompletaCantiereconPrezzo();
        s.db = db;
        s.IdCantiere = IdCantiere;
        s.Query = Query;
        s.Show();

        this.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Controlla che tutti i campi siano compilati correttamente, errore: "+ex);
    }
}
else if(comboBoxStampe.Text== "Stampa senza Prezzo")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Stampa Disabilitata");
}
else if (comboBoxStampe.Text == "Stampa Rapportini")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Stampa Disabilitata");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Devi selezionare una stampa");
}
```

Comment: Please, share the "Mostra Query"

Comment: @Riccardo Pirani "Input string was not in correct format" is NOT SQL Server error message. So it should be your C# error message

Comment: this code is wide open to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries to protect your data from being stolen, corrupted or deleted. http://bobby-tables.com/ explains the risks and also has clear examples of how to write your queries safely in C#

Comment: @ADyson I know it, I just write it so badly when I do some tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `'' as Quantita` to `0 as Quantita`

Comment: How can I fix the problem ? Instead of selecting the second checked box, the program does not enter the first if

Comment: If it's a `CheckedListBox` than use `CheckedIndices` it shows what was checked. `SelectedIndex` shows the current cursor position